# How to perform null-check before accessing the value in ref() of Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I face some errors where sometimes the `modelInfo` is not available to access.

**Note :**

> modelInfo?.value.model_owner

```
const summaryItems = ref({
  title: "Model Summary",
  items: {
    "Model Owner": getFullName(modelInfo?.value.model_owner),
  },
});
```

---

How do I add a null-check to `modelInfo` before accessing them ?

## I would

do this if I was in the block of codes :

```
if (modelInfo) {
    ...
}
```

and this if I was setting the value of the property

```
modelInfo || '';
```

... but I wasn't sure what to do in my case/situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```js
const summaryItems = ref({
  title: 'Model Summary',
  items: {
    'Model Owner': modelInfo ? getFullName(modelInfo.value.model_owner) : ''
  }
});
```

In this case if modelInfo is null the `Model Owner` property will be empty string but can be whatever fallback value you want.

Or maybe a ternary operator on the parent `items` property

```js
const summaryItems = ref({
  title: 'Model Summary',
  items: modelInfo ? { 'Model Owner': getFullName(modelInfo?.value.model_owner) } : null
});
```

where `items` will be null if `modelInfo` is null